# Deeplinking on flexslider

Tags: jquery, flexslider

How to create a deeplinking on flexslider just like the royal slider?

When I said deeplinking, if you click the thumbnail the url on the browser will going to chnage.. it is like a pointer for the slider...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use HTML5's History API, specifically `history.pushState()`. Then hook into the click event / slide display function and do something like

```
slide.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = this.dataset.href;
  history.pushState(null, null, href);
}, false);
```